# A question from Hilbert's Nullstellensatz

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

From the Hilbert's Nullstellensatz, we know that for any algebraic closed field $K$ and any prime ideal $p$ of $K[X_1,X_2,\cdots,X_n]$, the intersection of all the maximal ideals containing $p$ is $p$. Does this conclusion still hold for a general field $K$?

Comment: Yes, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobson_ring